# My FFMPEG throws me unexpected errors while writing a Thumbnail to the songs

Tags: ffmpeg, video-thumbnails

I am using Node to execute my ffmpeg. I use this wrapper:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg

Everything was fine when I was using smaller versions of the thumbnails provided by Youtube, but when I attempted the HD ones, it suddenly started giving me an error. I've tried -pix_fmt yuv422p and Many other pixel formats, but nothing helped. Though ONE out of 100+ songs did tag successfully.

here is my code:

```
downloadTags(tags.thumbnail, `./thumbnails/${tags.title}.jpg`).then(thumbnail =>
                    {
                        video.addCommand('-i', `"${thumbnail}"`);
                        video.addCommand('-map', '0');
                        video.addCommand('-map', '1');
                        video.addCommand('-c', 'copy');
                        video.addCommand('-c:v:1', 'png');
                        video.addCommand('-disposition:v:0', 'attached_pic');
                        if(tags.title)
                            video.addCommand('-metadata', `title="${tags.title}"`);
                        if(tags.artist)
                            video.addCommand('-metadata', `artist="${tags.artist}"`);
                        if(tags.id)
                            video.addCommand('-metadata', `comment="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${tags.id}"`);
                        video.addCommand('-pix_fmt', `yuv422p`);


                        var output = 'downloaded'
                        if (outFolder)
                        {
                            output = outFolder;
                            if(!fs.existsSync(output)) fs.mkdirSync(output);
                        }

                        video.save(`"./${output}/${tags.title}.${tags.format}"`, function (error, file) 
                        {
                            if (error)
                            {
                                resolve(error);
                                return
                            }
                            try
                            {
                                fs.unlinkSync(song);
                            }
                            catch(err)
                            {
                                console.log(err.code);
                            }
                            resolve();

                        });
                    });

                }
```

and here is my error:

E

```
RROR: Error: Command failed: ffmpeg -i "songs/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].m4a" -y  -i "./thumbnails/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].jpg" -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:0 attached_pic -metadata title="&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep]" -metadata artist="AReallyLongAndAwesomeNameThatIsBetterThanYoursInEveryPossibleWay" -metadata comment="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HprdvIIpR-I" "./written/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].m4a"
ffmpeg version N-93214-g7e4d3dbe18 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 47.102 / 58. 47.102
  libavformat    58. 26.101 / 58. 26.101
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002213366bb00] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'songs/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    title           : &I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep]
    artist          : Cider Party
    encoder         : Lavf58.18.104
    comment         : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HprdvIIpR-I
  Duration: 00:05:24.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 127 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 120x90 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Input #1, image2, from './thumbnails/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1575 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (mjpeg (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 00000221353d4fc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[ipod @ 00000221336703c0] Could not find tag for codec png in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:2 --
Conversion failed!
```

Keep in mind that All of my thumbnails retrieved are .jpg

Any suggestions? Getting really desperate at this point...

Answer (score 1):

Your audio input already has a cover image embedded, so when you set `-map 0 -map 1`, the cover image from the audio is mapped as the first video stream, and the new external image as  the 2nd video stream. Then you set `-disposition:v:0 attached_pic` which is applied to the already embedded image, and not the new one. In `.m4a`, MJPEG or PNG are only allowed for cover images, not regular video streams, and so the command fails.

If you only want the new image as thumbnail,

`ffmpeg -i "songs/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].m4a" -y  -i "./thumbnails/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].jpg" -map 0 -map -0:v -map 1 -c copy -c:v png -disposition:v attached_pic -metadata title="&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep]" -metadata artist="AReallyLongAndAwesomeNameThatIsBetterThanYoursInEveryPossibleWay" -metadata comment="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HprdvIIpR-I" "./written/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].m4a"`

If you need both,

`ffmpeg -i "songs/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].m4a" -y  -i "./thumbnails/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].jpg" -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v png -disposition:v attached_pic -metadata title="&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep]" -metadata artist="AReallyLongAndAwesomeNameThatIsBetterThanYoursInEveryPossibleWay" -metadata comment="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HprdvIIpR-I" "./written/&I feat. Giggly Maria - Dive (Exiark's Endless Sky Remix) [Chillstep].m4a"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try it out, I am very confused as to how the mapping works with ffmpeg, very new to it! ^^

Comment: Gyan, You are absolutely fantastic! It works perfectly, Thank You! I cannot believe how you managed to solve my entire problem without even knowing that my pictures already had thumbnails!!! I'm gonna look up to you :3 Thanks again!!